# Django how to save value to model without being present on form post

Tags: django

I have the following Model/form/view:

**Model**

```
class Account(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    identifier_type = models.ForeignKey(IdentifierType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    actflag = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.TextField(_(
        'comments'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    priority_type = models.ForeignKey(PriorityType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    deadline_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Form**

```
class PortfolioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    portfolio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['name', 'comments', 'priority_type', 'deadline_date', 'identifier_type', 'portfolio']
```

**View**

```
def portfolios(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        if request.POST:
            fm = PortfolioForm(request.POST)

            user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

            if fm.is_valid():
                messages.success(request, 'Portfolio has been created.')                

                fm.save()

                return redirect('portfolios')
        else:
            fm = PortfolioForm()

        context = {"name": request.user, "form": fm}

        return render(request, 'portfolios.html', context)

    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

The form works fine with posting via my template, however you will notice there are some fields within my model that are not in my form I would like to fill in automatically without the user having to fill in - for example username field I would like this to be current user that submits the form and also created_date would like the current date time the user has submitted the form.

I tried to add the following to my view under if fm.is_valid(): attempting to save username as current user to the model but did not work:

```
                Account.objects.username = request.user
```

How can I go about doing this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save these values after creating the `Account` object when you save the form. If you use the `commit=False` parameter in the `save` method, this does not hit the database and you can easy modify the `Account` object.

```py
from django.utils import timezone


def portfolios(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.POST:
            fm = PortfolioForm(request.POST)
            # user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

            if fm.is_valid():               
                account = fm.save(commit=False)
                account.username = request.user 
                account.created_date = timezone.now()
                account.save()

                messages.success(request, 'Portfolio has been created.') 
                return redirect('portfolios')
        else:
            fm = PortfolioForm()

        context = {"name": request.user, "form": fm}
        return render(request, 'portfolios.html', context)

    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use django forms `instance` for saving any predefined value without showing or render those fields to your users or html template. Here is an example how to automatically save your username and created_date fields .

```
if fm.is_valid():               
                fm = fm.save(commit=False)
                fm.instance.username = request.user  
                fm.instance.created_date = timezone.now()
                fm.save()
```